# Can I get speech recognition in language other than English on Android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to build an application (which would use the Hindi language and other regional languages) to get speech voice commands.

I also need text to speech functionality in my application.

I was wondering if there was any way I could get a speech recognition library on Android? I did a quick Google search and found a couple of libraries for Hindi on the Internet but I am not sure if I can include them in my Android project. Can I?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pocketsphinx for your app.It has JAVA and Python API's for capturing and recognizing speech. By default it recognizes only English. But if you provide your own Language Model (LM) and Dictionary File(.DIC), you should be able to get it working.

Not directly straightforward as using an API, but can be certainly doable

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Answer (score 0):

Android does support a few languages but not very many, I think the list currently is US, Japanese and Chinese. Not Hindi yet though I would think they are working to add new language support soon.

Over on the [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) they have a good example.