# Speech recognition: Hindi or Gujarti?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to make the speech recognizer get the result hindi or gujarti.
I try but I get the English.

How to Install the Hindi language in voice recognizer setting in android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from the [Google Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html):

> Google's servers support many
>   languages for voice input, with more
>   arriving regularly. You can use the
>   ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS broadcast
>   intent to query for the list of
>   supported languages.

Also, I found [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227434/can-i-get-speech-recognition-in-language-other-than-english-on-android) asking for basically the same (not sure if this is up-to-date anymore).